# Bash script shows error for "pwd", simple script

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, command-line-interface, shell

I'm trying to make a Bash shell script but it is not working.  Here is the contents of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

pwd
```

I would expect this to print out the current directory.  Instaed, it prints this:

```
: not found: build.sh: #!/bin/bash
: not found: build.sh:
: not found: build.sh: pwd
```

Why is it doing that?  I can't find any articles of other people having this problem.

I did chmod 777 on the script, and am running it like so:

```
sh build.sh
```

Comment: looks like some file format issue. Was the file created in linux or imported from windows? What gives the command 'file build.sh' ?

Comment: @tonioc I think you might be right!  It's being saved on Windows and uploaded.  What would the right encoding be?

Comment: @Abr The file probably has DOS/Windows-style line endings. See ["Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?" on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings/39527986#39527986). BTW, you should almost never use `chmod 777` (do you really want all users to be able to edit the script?), and run scripts with `./build.sh` rather than explicitly using `sh`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file probably has DOS/Windows-style line endings.

See "[Are shell scripts sensitive to encoding and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings/39527986#39527986)" on stackoverflow.

BTW, you should almost never use chmod 777 (do you really want all users to be able to edit the script?), and run scripts with ./build.sh rather than explicitly using sh.

– Gordon Davisson Jan 22 at 17:45

Comment: As this is more or less the accepted answer, I believe it should be filed as one.  Not taking credit, though.